# Any way to filter a treelist with just the source property of the template field?

Tags: templates, sitecore-query

I have a treelist that I'm pointing at a folder for items, which works fine, but when I attach some kind of filtering clause, like `/*[@@tid='{ID}']` it just defaults to the root of the sitecore content tree - i.e. it seems to just view the whole source as invalid and regards it as blank.  I've seen stuff around creating custom treelist controls, but trying to avoid having to do that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A treelist source can be set (and filtered) with a query. More info can be found here: https://getfishtank.ca/blog/treelist-data-source-hidden-functionality

This way you can include/exclude items or templates for display and/or selection. It is important to understand the difference between those. To be able to select the desired items, the tree needs to be able to display all parents to the desired item. So your displayed items is usually always more than the selection items. With the selection, you can determine which items from the displayed ones can be actually selected.

I guess you will need at least something like this:

```
datasource=/sitecore/content/.../folder&includetemplatesforselection=templatename
```

based on:

> **IncludeTemplatesForSelection** : A comma separated list of template names (no ids). Items are visible in the tree and can be selected.
>
> includetemplatesforselection=Item Name

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work.  I'm wondering if this is due to the field being a rendering parameter vs. a regular item field?

Comment: Just tested this (on a 9.0.2) in an rendering parameter template and works perfectly (using datasource and includetemplatesforselection) - edit the question and add the source you are using

Comment: Seems like I also needed the &IncludeItemsForDisplay in order to specify the specific items, in addition to the &includetemplatesforselection=templatename.  Now that I have both I'm able to filter properly, thanks for the help.